# How do you define constant variables like this in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

```
const data_types_Code: Coding = {
   code: "code",
   display: "code",
   system: "http://hl7.org/fhir/data-types"
};
```

How do we define this in Solidity? The above code is in TypeScript

Comment: Why do you need to declare it as constant? In solidity you can declare values as constant like this `string constant x = "x"`, but not structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solidity, you would define the type `Coding` as a struct as follows:

```
struct Coding {
   string code;
   string display;
   string system;
}
```

But then when it comes to defining the constant value, it would not be possible in Solidity at the time of writing. Solidity would give you the following error: `TypeError: Only constants of value type and byte array type are implemented.`.

You could still initialize `data_types_Code` as a storage variable as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract Example {
    struct Coding {
        string code;
        string display;
        string system;
    }

    Coding public data_types_Code = Coding({
        code: "code",
        display: "code",
        system: "http://hl7.org/fhir/data-types"
    });
}
```